# Ansible change connection from winrm to ssh between task

Tags: ansible

I have had an issue with connecting to local_action when running my playbook, my playbook is used to create users in SQL Server and need to run local action to get generate random password

```
fatal: [w961412]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ntlm: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4572858790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))", "unreachable": true}
```

task for ssh

```
- name: get random password
  command: tr -dc 'A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z2-9' < /dev/urandom | dd bs=12 count=1 status=none
  register: secret
```

tasks for winrm:

```
- name: Alter database credentials.
  win_shell: | 
       sqlcmd -S {{ sql_hostname }},{{ SQL_PORT }} -E -q "alter login {{ dbuser }} with password=N'{{ secret.password }}'" -o alter.log 
 register: alter_result
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foremost, what you said is actually correct: you want a **local** action; I don't think it needs to connect back to your control host over ssh just to generate a password

So, I would expect you could use:

```
- name: get a random password
  connection: local
  shell: tr -dc 'A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z2-9' < /dev/urandom | dd bs=12 count=1 status=none
  register: secret
- win_shell: |
    echo "and now you are back to the normal playbook connection"
```

Your code snippet also had a bug in it by trying to use `command:` with a string containing a pipe -- shell operators are not supported by `command:`, that's why `shell:` exists

Then, separately, you don't have to use a bunch of shell commands, along with some magic `tr` string literal: ansible has a [random password lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/password.html#password-retrieve-or-generate-a-random-password-stored-in-a-file) such that you can:

```
- win_shell: |
     sqlcmd -q "alter login with password=N'{{ item }}'"
  register: alter_result
  with_password: /dev/null length=12
```